# How to properly use concepts?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts, if-constexpr

Currently, I am learning C++ and decided just start with C++20. However, these codes are driving me crazy, since I don't think the result makes any sense.

The following code will have the sentence `Valid array.` printed.  What I meant above is that this is not right. It shouldn't print the sentence at all, since the type I inserted in the parameter doesn't match the concept.

Tested on VS2022 Preview 3 and [an online compiler](https://wandbox.org/) with newest GCC and C++2A(GNU) arguments, generated the same results.

```
#include <array>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

template<typename A> concept ProperArray = requires(A array)
{
    {array.max_size() >= 2U};
    {std::is_arithmetic_v<typename A::value_type> == true};
};

int main()
{
    constexpr bool b = ProperArray<array<std::string, 1>>;
    if constexpr (b)
        cout << "Valid array." << endl;
        
    std::cout << "Hello, Wandbox!" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: You should move the constexpr  check to a template function, it will only work with template functions. main is not a template function.

Comment: For one, you are using the wrong type of requirements. `{array.max_size() >= 2U};` checks that the expression is syntactically correct, not that `max_size` is really over 2. Same for `std::is_arithmetic_v<typename A::value_type> == true`.

Comment: @Const I am sure that ``if constexpr`` works in normal functions as well. If I replace the ``b`` with ``false`` in parentheses, the sentence will not be printed.

Comment: @StoryTeller - Unslander Monica Thank you for your information! Then what should I do to check the size of an std::array? Is it even possible? And what should I do to properly imply the arithmetic check?

Comment: Why would a "proper" array have more than one element? An array of only a single element is still an array. What is the *real* problem you're trying to solve with a concept like that?

Comment: @Some programmer dude It has nothing to do with naming, it is about practicing C++20..

Comment: So this is more about curiosity than attempting to solve a real problem? Then please include that in the question itself. Otherwise I recommend you try to ask about the problem directly instead (and include all requirements and limitations, and also mention this concept as your attempt to solve the problem).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So, two things.

1. You are using [simple requirements](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints#Simple_requirements) (the extra `{}` make those compound requirements technically, but since you don't use any optional feature of those, it's equivalent to a simple requirement). Those mostly verify that an expression is syntactically valid. Its value is immaterial to them. What you want is [*nested requirements*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints#Nested_requirements):

   ```
   template<typename A> concept ProperArray = requires(A array)
   {
       //requires array.max_size() >= 2U;
       requires std::is_arithmetic<typename A::value_type>::value;
   };
   ```

   These requirements (whose expression must be a constant expression), check the value indeed. Mind however, that the parameters [can only be used in unevaluated contexts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74304301/817643), so you'll need another way to query the type for it's size. That may change in some way or form in the future.
2. `if constexpr` outside of a template is moot. It doesn't do the same discarding magic it does when its condition is value-dependent on a template parameter. You could have used a regular `if` to the same effect.

Comment: Is this code meant to work? As you've [put it yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74304572/7107236): aren't you trying to use a non-existent object in (constant-)evaluation of an expression?

Comment: @303 - Should be more accurate now. I found no promising progress on making it valid today, though.

Comment: What about dropping the parameter-list of the requires clause and using `requires A{}.max_size() >= 2U;` instead?

Comment: @303 - That should work, I believe.