# Invalid constraint expression

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

The following [code example](https://godbolt.org/z/4czTe9eE8) doesn't compile with Clang 15 or Clang trunk, in contrast to GCC 12.2 and MSVC 19.33. Is the contraint expression in the nested required clause invalid?

```
struct t {
    constexpr auto b() const noexcept
    { return true; }
};

template<typename T>
concept c = requires(T t) {
    requires t.b();
};

static_assert(c<t>);
```

The error message produced by Clang:

```
<source>:11:1: error: static assertion failed
static_assert(c<t>);
^             ~~~~
<source>:11:15: note: because 't' does not satisfy 'c'
static_assert(c<t>);
              ^
<source>:8:14: note: because 't.b()' would be invalid: constraint variable 't'
cannot be used in an evaluated context
    requires t.b();
             ^
```

---

Interestingly, the fault also becomes apparent with GCC when wrapping the evaluation of `t.b()` in a `std::bool_constant`. When changing the constraint expression as such:

```
template<typename T>
concept c = requires(T t) {
    requires std::bool_constant<t.b()>::value;
};
```

GCC will actually produce the following error, while MSVC is still fine with it:

```
<source>:15:38: error: template argument 1 is invalid
   15 |     requires std::bool_constant<t.b()>::value;
```

Comment: `t` is not a constant expression.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> **[expr.prim.req.general]** (emphasis mine)
>
> [4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.prim.req.general#4.sentence-4) A requires-expression may introduce local parameters using a parameter-declaration-clause ([dcl.fct]). A local parameter of a requires-expression shall not have a default argument. Each name introduced by a local parameter is in scope from the point of its declaration until the closing brace of the requirement-body. **These parameters have no linkage, storage, or lifetime;** they are only used as notation for the purpose of defining requirements. [...]

You are trying to use a non-existent object in (constant-)evaluation of an expression, it's not *meant* to work. Think of the parameters of compound requires expression as shorthand `declval`. You can use them in unevaluated contexts, examine the types and such, but not evaluate with them.

To be explicit

> [expr.prim.req.nested]
>
> [2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.prim.req.nested#2) A local parameter shall only appear as an unevaluated operand within the constraint-expression.
> [Example 2:
>
> ```
> template<typename T> concept C = requires (T a) {
>   requires sizeof(a) == 4;      // OK
>   requires a == 0;              // error: evaluation of a constraint > variable
> };
> ```
>
> — end

So Clang is the only correct compiler out of the bunch.

Comment: I wonder though whether "_shall_" here doesn't apply to the definition itself. Shouldn't it be a hard error, not only evaluate the clause to `false`?

Comment: @user17732522 - Mmm... You are more attentive than I. Yes, it's a shall-requirement and should error immediately. I wonder if it's because concepts are new beasts that aren't traditionally instantiaated, so Clang doesn't treat it as regular templates to check for ill-formdness prior to instantation.

Comment: After writing my previous comment I realized that generally this can only be determined after substitution because of `typeid`'s behavior, so at least the example is weird since it implies the error on the definition. And https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.prim.req#general-6.sentence-6 says that it would then be ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

Comment: @user17732522 - I dunno. `typeid` aside, a nested `requires` expressionis not conditionally evaluated, and a shall requirement is a shall requirement still

Comment: @user17732522 - On the other hand... yeah I think your reading is also valid. So I'll just remove discussion of that conclusion.

Comment: Ironically, the code in question is a reduced version of the answer that you've posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68801477/7107236).

Comment: @303 - Indeed. Benefit of hindsight and all that. Though I wonder if there's a standing open issue about this with wg21. I might have to amend one or both answers.

Comment: @303 - Well, the explicit paragraph itself is contentious https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2517 - Now I wonder whether there's desire to make your code well-formed (because let's face it, `t` isn't really used for the constant evaluation)