# Unexpanded parameter pack in constraint-expression

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

The following [code example](https://godbolt.org/z/ePcb9nPdT) doesn't compile with GCC 12.2 or GCC trunk, in contrast to Clang 15 and MSVC 19.33. Is the expansion of the parameter pack in the constraint-expression invalid?

```
struct s {
    constexpr auto b() const
    { return true; }
};

template<typename... Ts>
concept c = (requires(Ts ts) {
    ts.b();            // error on GCC
    { ts.b() };        // error on GCC
    requires Ts{}.b(); // error on GCC
    Ts{}.b();          // ok on all
    { Ts{}.b() };      // ok on all
} and ...);

static_assert(c<s>);
```

The error message produced by GCC:

```
<source>:7:14: error: operand of fold expression has no unexpanded parameter packs
    7 | concept c = (requires(Ts ts) {
      |              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Dupe: [Invalid constraint expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74304301/invalid-constraint-expression)..

Comment: @JasonLiam I'm pretty sure I didn't post the same question twice...

Comment: FWIW, `template<typename... Ts> concept c = requires(Ts... ts) { (ts.b(), ...); };` works with all of the compilers

Comment: @303 As explained in the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74304301/invalid-constraint-expression), *"A local parameter shall only appear as an unevaluated operand within the constraint-expression"*, which means `ts.b()` is still ill-formed. Ask yourself if here you're using `ts` in an unevaluated context or not.

Comment: @JasonLiam You're wrong, `ts.b();` is a simple requirement for which is stated: *"The expression is an unevaluated operand; only language correctness is checked."*. And your explanation still doesn't explain why the nested requirement `requires Ts{}.b();` produces an error.

Comment: @303 Change `requires Ts{}.b();` to `sizeof Ts{}.b();` and the program will start compiling with gcc as well.

Comment: I believe the first two errors are a gcc bug manifesting https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=107417 - The third might be more of the same, but I did not find a confirmed bug report.

Comment: It feels I reed the question already some days before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74304301/invalid-constraint-expression, but now the problem is extended by a parameter pack which is not expanded like `requires(Ts... ts)`. So why we see it now two times?

Comment: @Klaus Because this post involves a completely different problem with a completely different compiler. The post you're referring to, which indeed involves contraint-expressions as well, is about using a non-existing object in (constant-)evaluation of an expression. This problem involves either an unevaluated operand or an existing (albeit temporary) object within a constraint-expression.